# Retrieve up-to-date TLS cipher suite with python

Tags: python, ssl, encryption

I already tried to utilize `openssl ciphers`, but the format is different and I have to match them with a given set of ciphers. I also tried to translate the OpenSSL cipher suite format into the one I need, but that's a mess.
Hence, I'm searching for a way to retreive an up-to-date TLS cipher suite list with python in the appropriate format. Maybe there's even some Web-Interface?

Here are some examples:

```
   The Format I need                       OpenSSL Format
   ---------------------------------       ---------------------       
   SSL_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA               IDEA-CBC-SHA
   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA       DHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA            AES256-SHA
```

Comment: There are tables available of both conversions online, which can simply be formatted as .csv and used as a resource (OpenSSL -> 16 bit ID -> official string. But I don't see how you can do this when new ciphers are introduced by the runtime. I presume relying on online internet resources is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, I found a [place](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xml) where officially registered cipher suites are listed, that also offers a `.csv`-[download](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters-4.csv). I guess I will just use that list. However, I could neither find a way to retrieve the 16 Bit ID from OpenSSL.

Comment: I think the crypt command can retrieve them, but I also found tables online, I also found [this table](https://testssl.sh/openssl-rfc.mappping.html)